# type module with function already implemented ocaml

Tags: module, ocaml

I have a module type `Order` which will be implemented in several modules.
The function compare will be implemented in the modules.

```
module type Order = 
sig
  type t
  val compare: t -> t -> int
end
```

I want also create a function max :

```
max a b = if (compare a b > 0) then a else b
```

I would like to write the definition (Not just declaring ) of this function in my module Order in order to avoid to rewrite the same definition in the submodule which are numerous.

I have tried :

```
val max a b = if (compare a b > 0) then a else b
```

and

```
let max a b = if (compare a b > 0) then a else b
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't implement functions in the signature of a module.
I think that the problem you are having is solved using [functors](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/functors.html) in OCaml.

A code example you can look at to understand how it works is the implementation of [Set](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/set.ml).

In your case it would look something like:
EDIT: taking into consideration Richard Degenne, octachron and PatJ contributions:

```
module type Order =
sig
  type t
  val compare: t -> t -> int
end

module type Util =
sig
  type t
  val compare: t -> t -> int
  val max: t -> t -> t
end

module Make(Ord: Order): Util with type t := Ord.t =
struct
  type t = Ord.t
  let compare = Ord.compare
  let max a b = if (Ord.compare a b > 0) then a else b
end
```

In order to use it you can do:

```
(*You first define a module for the specific case of int*)
module IntOrder = struct
  type t = int
  let compare = compare
end

(*You use the new module to build the corresponding Util module*)
module IntUtil = Make(IntOrder)

(*You can now use the functions defined in Util as if it was any other module*)
let x = IntUtil.max 1 2
let y = IntUtil.compare 1 2

(*But if you try to call it with the wrong type you get an error*)
let z = IntUtil.compare 1.6 2.5
```

Comment: You could use `Util` as the module signature of the functor for clarity : `module Make(Ord : Order) : Util = struct ... end`.

Comment: You need `Util with type t := Ord.t` (or `with type t = Ord.t`)  otherwise the type equality is lost, making it impossible to use `max` on terms of type `Ord.t`.

Comment: Thank you, added you contribution.

Comment: To fit the question, you may want to add `compare` to `Util`.